# Rendering json data in react js error: 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'item')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

So I am trying to render some data from a json file in react js, but when I try to run it, it always show an error that it cannot read the parent of a certain data from the json because it's undefined even though I am sure that I put it right.

Json file:

```json
{
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "item"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```js
const main = ({ backEndData }) => {
  return (
    <div className='main'>
        {
            backEndData.items.item.forEach(product => {
                return (
                    <p>{product.name}</p>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Error:

[image]

I am getting the json file from my backend server btw

Comment: Have you tried to debug this at all? Putting console.logs in the code to work out what's happening? Looking at the network requests? Are you trying to `map` over data that hasn't got to the front end yet? How are you initialising your state? You can do all of this.

Comment: did you try optional chaining?

Comment: Show us ***exactly*** what is `backEndData` (use `console.log(backEndData);` before `return`)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read about the difference between map and foreach (forEach never return smth). Try displaying items in the console (they are not defined). I can assume that your code will look like this:

```
backEndData.item.map(product => 
  <p>{product.name}</p>
);
```